# python, how to save tkinter image?

Tags: image, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

i found a code that opens the typical "Save-as"-window, but if i want to save my tkinter image as, for example .jpg, it only saves a .jpg file without image. The other options arnt working too.

Example code:

```
### this class will open a safe-file-as standart menu
class TkFileDialogExample(Tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):

        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        button_opt = {'fill': Tkconstants.BOTH, 'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        Tkinter.Button(self, text='asksaveasfilename', \
                       command = self.asksaveasfilename).pack(**button_opt)


        self.file_opt = options = {}
        options['filetypes'] = [('all files', '.*'), ('text files', '.txt'),
                                ('jpeg image', '.jpg'), ('png image', '.png'),
                                ('tiff image', '.tiff'), ('bmp image', '.bmp')]

        options['initialfile'] = 'myfile.txt'
        options['parent'] = root

    def asksaveasfilename(self):
        filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(**self.file_opt)

        if filename:
            return image.save(filename)
```

Here is my "open a image in tkinter" code:

```
##this  function will open an image in a canvas, but the functions
   #expects a picture. It also converts a image into a TKinter photo image#
def imgShow(master, img):

    #convert lena.jpg into tkinter photo image
    global image 
    image = Image.open(img)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    #create canvas to display picture
    w = Canvas(master)
    w.photo = photo


    w.create_image(0, 0, image = photo, anchor = "nw")
    w.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = YES)

    return image
```

Maybe you know how to save the image.

Comment: `image.save(filename)`

Comment: i changed the photo variable to global and added a "return photo" but if i change "image.save(filename)" to photo.save(filename)" it says "'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'save'"

Comment: Now its working!! Thanks furas!!